# Flutter project on Mac M1: Module not found

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio, cocoapods, apple-m1

I have a Flutter project that works properly on and Intel Mac. Now I'm trying to build on a MacBook Pro with M1 chip and I'm stuck at `Module 'xxx' not found` in `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m`.

On the same machine project builds using Android Studio, but not on Xcode. Podfile is the standard one generated by Flutter.

I've tried all kind of solutions and commands around ffi, cocoapods, rosetta without luck.

Any idea?